# Why function definition has multiple return types in C

Tags: c

I'm just learning C language, and knew how to write a function:

```c
return_type function_name() {}
```

It seems that only one *return type* could been written at definition, however, I seen some styles in Win32 API and Android JNI cound also been compiled successful:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc()
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName()
```

I'm confused why they are two or three return types. I searched and found these may be **modifiers**, but what I learned the modifiers should be `static`, `long`, `unsigned` those keywords.

Comment: `LRESULT` and `CALLBACK` likely are macro definitions, they are substituted by preprocessor before compilation. Also not only modifiers may be present but for example function attributes.

Comment: are you sure that WindowProc() and Java_ClassName_MethodName() are actually C and not something else?

Comment: These macros are described on the [Windows Data Types page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).  `LRESULT` specifies the return type.  `CALLBACK` specifies the calling convention.  There are no alternate return types involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CALLBACK`, `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` are not types; those are macros that may expand to some platform-specific language extensions to declare some other properties of the function.

In this case, `CALLBACK` and `JNICALL` are used to declare the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for those functions. `JNIEXPORT` will be used to mark that the function is exported (when building the library) or imported (when linking against the library) when dynamic linking is used.

These details are necessary to provide libraries with stable ABI (Application Binary Interface). These details are, however, outside the scope of the C standard. They also depend on the platform and configuration that the library is built on. Therefore library writers resort to using macros that expand to the appropriate platform-specific syntax depending on the scenario that the code is compiled in.

Answer (score 0):

You may also sometimes encounter different typedef'd names for what are actually the same type. This is particularly common with windows due to having absorbed an enormous number of typedef'd names over the years.

For example, LRESULT and LONG_PTR resolve to the same actual type, at least on x86 systems (haven't checked non-x86).

so:

```
LONG_PTR foo();
```

and

```
LRESULT foo();
```

actually declare the same function.